# suphp directory not owned by user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, php, apache-httpd, suphp

I have an odd problem with suphp.

I have logged in as tom and added some php to a directory in my web server.

Now I'm getting this error:

```
Directory /home/.../web/public_html is not owned by tom
```

I can't/won't change the ownership of public_html as various different users may be contributing to the site in this way.

Is there a configuration in suphp I need to edit in order to allow this to work?

Comment: note that if you are letting other users put php into a directory, where it will be run as user tom, you are letting them run arbitrary commands as tom already

Comment: As far as I can tell this is a design choice. I think it's stupid to have though. The single document root, along with no symlinks should make this unnecessary https://lists.marsching.com/pipermail/suphp/2008-April/001831.html

Comment: how did u solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
chown root.root /
```

That command worked for me

Answer (score -1):

*suphp* does not have such an option. AFAIK you have to solve it with real users and permissions.